# How can I to prevent left join returns more records than in the unjoined query?

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm trying to join multiple tables by using Left Join in order to get only the found records according to the id field the from main table (table_a):

```
Select table_a.id, table_b.location, table_c.material
From table_a
Left Join table_b
On table_a.id = table_b.id
Left Join table_c
On table_a.id = table_c.id
```

Everything seems to go fine here, i'm getting the expected fields in the output and also, the number of records is 11,000 (the same as the table_a)

But when I add the next left join on the query, using on the id field of the tabl_b and not based on the id field of table:a instead, I get 11,500 records:

```
Select table_a.id, table_b.location, table_c.material, table_d.sales
From table_a
Left Join table_b
On table_a.id = table_b.id
Left Join table_c
On table_a.id = table_c.id
Left Join table_d.id 
On table_b.id = table_d.id
```

Do you know how I can prevent this issue?

Comment: Some table_b rows match multiple table_d rows.

Comment: right, but what if I just need to keep the records from the main table (table_a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason why the table_d has more than 1 match with table_b. Here it is important to consider the business rules of your problem. Usually we can't just simple ignore the multiple result, either we need to group the extra columns, sum, average, or choose one of the multiple matches based on a certain rule. For example, here I assume that from table_d I want the most recent record match, which is month column. I use rank and partition in order to get an ID for which to order the "duplicates", in this case I only want the first match (order_c = 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
  Select table_a.id, table_b.location, table_c.material, table_d.sales
, RANK() OVER (partition by table_a.id order by table_d.month desc) as order_c
  From table_a
Left Join table_b
On table_a.id = table_b.id
Left Join table_c
On table_a.id = table_c.id
Left Join table_d
On table_b.id = table_d.id)

select id, location, material, sales, order_c 
from cte where order_c =1
```

You can see the [fiddle in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdd69/9).

```
create table table_a (ID INT);
create table table_b (ID INT, location varchar(10));
create table table_c (ID INT, material varchar(10));
create table table_d (ID INT, sales INT, month INT);
INSERT into table_a(ID) 
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
INSERT into table_b(ID, location) 
VALUES (1, 'UK'),
      (9, 'USA');
INSERT into table_c(ID, material) 
VALUES (1, 'paper');
INSERT into table_d(ID, sales, month) 
VALUES (1, 345, 1), (1, 599, 2);
```